# C sscanf and string format

Tags: c, string, format, scanf

I have a little bit of a problem while understanding the sscanf string formatting.

I have that string stored in **str**: `192.168.0.100/act?bla=`

I want with this code to have **bla** stored inside my "key" variable and the remaining stuff (after the '=') in my "buf" variable

```
char str[] = "192.168.0.100/act?bla=";
char key[20];
char buf[100];
sscanf(str, "%*[^?] %[^=] %s", key, buf);
```

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan, don't you mean `snprintf`?

Comment: @StoryTeller Ahaa! yes you are correct... nothing is `snscanf`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `?` and `=` will not be consumed so include them in the format specifier:

```
sscanf(str, "%*[^?]?%[^=]=%s", key, buf);
```

See demo at http://ideone.com/YoRMh3 .

To prevent buffer overrun specify the maximum number of characters that can be read by each specifier, one less than the target array to allow for null termination, and ensure that both arrays were populated by checking the return value of `sscanf()`:

```
if (2 == sscanf(str, "%*[^?]?%19[^=]=%99s", key, buf))
{
    printf("<%s>\n", key);
    printf("<%s>\n", buf);
}
```

In order to ensure that the `buf` value is not truncated, you can use the `%n` format specifier that populates an `int` indicating the position at which processing stopped (note the `%n` has no effect on the return value of `sscanf()`). If the entire input was processed the end position is `strlen(str)`:

```
int pos;
if (2 == sscanf(str, "%*[^?]?%19[^=]=%5s%n", key, buf, &pos) &&
    strlen(str) == pos)
{
    printf("<%s>\n", key);
    printf("<%s>\n", buf);
}
```

Comment: +1 You should also limit the number of read characters to avoid overflows of your arrays:

`sscanf(str, "%*[^?]?%20[^=]=%100s", key, buf);`

Comment: @AdriánLópez, yep. Had just occurred to me but had not updated yet. Thanks.

Comment: Thx a lot for your quick and precise answer!!  :)

Comment: @hmjd Is it possible to use sscanf to match a string if for example we have : `char str[] = "192.168.0.100/act??bla="`;and we want to match `??` instead of `?` can this be done

Answer (score 1):

You can add the exptected characters so they will be read and ignored:

```
sscanf(str, "%*[^?]?%[^=]=%s", key, buf);
```

Note that '?' and '=' are still in the stream and aren't read after `[^=]` is processed.